# Error 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in underscore.js'

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js, template-engine

Here's my code,

**HTML:**

```
<script type="text/html" id="test_temp">
    <div class="row" id="opportunityList">
        <% _.each(ops, function(option){
            <div class="span12">
                <div class="well basicInformation">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="span4 opportunityName" >
                            <h4><%= option.company_name %></h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="span4 pull-right">
                            <ul class="inline">
                                <li class="dealGrade">
                                    <span><%= option.dealGrade %></span>
                                    <span class="subheader">Deal Grade</span>
                                </li>
                                <li class="estimateddevices">
                                    <span><%= option.devices %></span>
                                    <span class="subheader">Devices</span>
                                </li>
                                <li class="accountValue">
                                    <span><%= option.accountValue %></span>
                                    <span class="subheader">Account value</span>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        });
        %>
    </div>
</script>
```

**SCRIPT:**

```
testView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(){
        this.render();
    },

    render: function(){
        var ops = [
            {dealGrade: '50%', devices: 123, accountValue: '20%', company_name: 'Kyocera', rep_name: 'James Kogg', rep_designation: 'Sales Rep', proposalCount: 2},
            {dealGrade: '75%', devices: 215, accountValue: '41%', company_name: 'Flipkart', rep_name: 'Christina Kogg', rep_designation: 'MD', proposalCount: 0}
        ]

        var template = _.template($("#test_temp").html(), ops);

        this.$el.append(template);
    }
});

var test_view = new testView({ el: $("#viewport .container") });
```

I get this error message:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in underscore.js

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not closing the `<%` around the `_.each` or opening the template tag for the `_.each`'s  closing `});`:

```
<script type="text/html" id="test_temp">
   <div class="row" id="opportunityList">
     <% _.each(ops, function(option){ %>
       ...
     <% }); %>
   </div>
</script>
```

Underscore's template engine is pretty simple minded, it just does a bit of simple text wrangling to turn your template inside-out into JavaScript code.

Also, the template function wants its data as key/value pairs (i.e. a JavaScript object) so you'll need to give your `ops` a name:

```
var template = _.template($("#test_temp").html(), { ops: ops });
```

Comment: whoaa, ok, that's weird syntax, that got resolved, but now it says `ops` is not defined

Comment: Still not working, getting the same error, my script files are loading after `#test_temp`, is that correct or do I need to change that?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `{ ops: ops }`, not `{ opts: ops }`?

Comment: @Lukas: Right, thanks, my fingers don't always type what my brain thinks they should :)

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar error

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token `var`
>       at new Function ()
>       at Function._.template

that's because in my template I wrote a js statement inside `<%=` instead of `<%`

so make sure the syntax of your template is correct